# Php pdo_db lib bind error

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo

I can easly execute in php through pdo_dblib query like this:

```
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS _NO
        FROM [Reports].[dbo].[Cycle] 
    ) AS SOD
    WHERE SOD._NO BETWEEN (( :page -1)* :rows )+1
    AND :rows * 2
    ");
            $stmt->bindValue('page', 2);
            $stmt->bindValue('rows', 2);

            $stmt->execute();
            print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

result:

```
    Array
    (
        [0] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 4608
                [StartTime] => Apr 15 2014 06:00:00:000PM
                [EndTime] => Apr 16 2014 09:30:00:000AM
                [ComputeTime] => May 29 2014 04:33:35:743PM
                [ComputeSettlementTime] => May 29 2014 04:34:49:063PM
                [_NO] => 3
            )

        [1] => Array
            (
                [ID] => 4609
                [StartTime] => Apr 16 2014 09:30:00:000AM
                [EndTime] => Apr 16 2014 10:00:00:000AM
                [ComputeTime] => May 29 2014 04:34:05:927PM
                [ComputeSettlementTime] => May 29 2014 04:34:49:297PM
                [_NO] => 4
            )

    )
```

but if i try to set parameter "page" second time in place of "2" in this query like parameter 'rows' already used twice in the same query, i have result:

```
            $stmt = $pdo->prepare("
    SELECT *
    FROM (
        SELECT *,
        ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY ID) AS _NO
        FROM [Reports].[dbo].[Cycle] 
    ) AS SOD
    WHERE SOD._NO BETWEEN (( :page -1)* :rows )+1
    AND :rows * :page
    ");
            $stmt->bindValue('page', 2);
            $stmt->bindValue('rows', 2);

            $stmt->execute();
            print_r($stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC));
```

result is:

```
PHP Fatal error:  Uncaught exception 'PDOException' with message 'SQLSTATE[HY000]: General error: 8117 General SQL Server error: Check messages from the SQL Server [8117] (severity 16) [(null)]'
```

and this error code i cant'find on error table: 8117. 
Does anyone know what is going on?

Comment: Missing `:`   try `$stmt->bindValue(':page', 2);`

Comment: @JitendraYadav That wouldn't matter.

Answer (score 0):

You should name each placeholders differently and bind it.

```
$stmt->bindValue('page1', 2);
$stmt->bindValue('page2', 2);
...
```